# How to resolve importError after installing python pysctp in ubuntu:_sctp.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:undefined symbol:PyString_FromStringAndSize

Tags: python, sctp, python-bindings

I have installed `pysctp` python module (python version: 3.5.2, Ubuntu :16.04). But when I am trying to import it I am getting importError as:

```
ImportError: /home/labuser/framework/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_sctp.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyString_FromStringAndSize
version:
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

I have already installed required dependencies: `libsctp-dev`, `python-dev` and/or `python3-dev`

```
pip install pysctp
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sctp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/labuser/framework/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sctp.py", line 55, in <module>
    import _sctp
ImportError: /home/labuser/framework/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_sctp.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyString_FromStringAndSize
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the package `pysctp` because I got an error message when installing the package using the pip command `pip install pysctp` and `pip3 install pysctp` on Ubuntu 18.04. You may have to report the issue to them in their github repository at https://github.com/P1sec/pysctp.